# Golang: Could not understand how below code is executing

Tags: arrays, go

Below is the code I have a query upon:
I have a single dimentional array a
I could not understand when i printing `a[0][0]` then why it is returning ascii value of the character `a`:

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {

        a := [3]string{"a","b","c"} 

        fmt.Println(a[0][0])
 }
```

Output: **97**

Comment: `a[0]` is a `string`, `a[0][0]` is the first byte of this `string`, which is a `byte`, a value of type `uint8`, and its value is `97` (which is the code for character `a`) which you see printed.

Comment: `a` is an array of three strings that each happen to only be one character long.  `a[0]` is the string `"a"`. So `a[0][0]` is the first character of that string which has ASCII value 97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the example of code on how it print ascii

```
a := [3]string{"a","b","c"} 

for _, rune := range a {
   fmt.Println(rune)// It will print a,b,c
}
```

since you used a[0][0] in your code it is equivalent

```
for _, rune := range a {
   fmt.Println(rune[0])// It will print 97,98,99
   // rune is equal to x := 'a'
   // when you write it like x := 'a' and
   // fmt.Println(x) the output is 97
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are misunderstanding how to access to a string in a slice (Golang discurage the use of [array](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)). If you are interesting to print a single value inside the slice you should do

```
fmt.Println(a[0]) --> print a
fmt.Println(a[1]) --> print b
fmt.Println(a[2]) --> print c
```

What you are doing in your code is to access to the first element of the string (so you are accessing to the byte of the string which is in that case 97 the 'a' value).

Comment: Go has both arrays and slices. Array are fixed in length. [3]string is an array type.

Comment: Yeah but an explicit usage of array is discurage in Golang since the "slice" are more flexible. But I get it what you are say, I'll fix the question

Comment: Go doesn't discourage arrays, they are used all the time _when they are appropriate_ (the article you linked says nothing about discouraging usage of arrays, just that they are less common)

Comment: Uhm if you say so maybe I was wrong to understand what the point of the sentence since IMHO if you try to avoid the usage of array there is a reason for that, or am I wrong?